# How to merge columns in a rails table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merge

I have a rails table of users, with columns first_name and last_name etc.
How do i merge these two together? Or how do i create a new column called name and add data from these two columns?
Basically i need a column called name which is the concatenation of the first_name and last_name.

Comment: What are you trying to solve?  For example - Do you need it for sorting?  Displaying in a view?  Do you want to change a form to accept a single field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make sure you can rollback, you can do something like this in your migration file.

```
  def up
    add_column :your_table, :name, :string 

    YourClass.all.each do |person|
      person.update_attributes! :name => person.first_name + " " + person.last_name
    end

    remove_column :your_table, :first_name
    remove_column :your_table, :last_name  
  end
```

And your down method for the roll back:

```
  def down
    add_column :your_table, :first_name, :string
    add_column :your_table, :last_name, :string

    YourClass.all.each do |person|
      person.update_attributes! :first_name => person.name.match(/\w+/)[0]
      person.update_attributes! :last_name => person.name.match(/\w+/)[1]
    end

    remove_column :your_table, :name
  end
```

Comment: Very helpful, but shouldn't the 'down' include the :your_table as well?  It would be unfortunate if someone needed to rollback and found it didn't work and didn't remember where they got the answer.  :)

Comment: Absolutely. I corrected it. Thanks @DavidLjungMadison

Comment: It's a bad practice to use models in migrations since your code will evolve (e.g. your model might disappear or get renamed someday). But as [this article describes](http://blog.makandra.com/2010/03/how-to-use-models-in-your-migrations-without-killing-kittens/) you can inline the model classes and you are making sure the migration will run even when the model disappeared. Just (re)define the `YourClass` model in the migration class to be future-proof.

Answer (score 6):

As Richard Brown has answered, you should create a migration if you want to save the concatenated string to the database.

```
rails g migration add_fullname_to_users fullname
```

then run an sql inside the generated migration to update all records

```
# mysql
User.update_all('fullname = CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name)')

# postgre
User.update_all("fullname = (first_name || ' ' || last_name)")
```

But I'd suggest you just keep your current setup and just create a method called fullname in your model

```
# user.rb
def fullname
  "{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

which is better since you have access to `first_name` and `last_name`

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration to add the new field:

`rails g migration AddNameToTableName name`

You can write a rake task to do the join.

```
TableName.all.each do { |row| row.update_attributes(name: "#{row.first_name} #{row.last_name}") }
```

You can execute that from the rails console, but I like repeatable database updates so I prefer a rake task.

Answer (score 0):

The \w regex matcher and concatenating with spaces as in the above examples were problematic for me, although I had the **opposite** problem, splitting a name into first and last names.  Instead, consider using what I ended up with. Back up your databases first, and test this in development!

```
  def up # Split name into first and last
    add_column :people, :first_name, :string
    add_column :people, :last_name, :string
    Person.all.each do |person|
      person.update_column(:first_name, person.attributes["name"].rpartition(" ").first)
      person.update_column(:last_name, person.attributes["name"].rpartition(" ").last)
      person.save(:validate => false)
    end
    remove_column :people, :name
  end

  def down # Merge first and last into name
    add_column :people, :name, :string
    Person.all.each do |person|
      person.update_column(:name, [person.attributes["first_name"].to_s, person.attributes["last_name"].to_s].reject(&:blank?).join(" "))
      person.save(:validate => false)
    end
    remove_column :people, :first_name
    remove_column :people, :last_name
  end
```

This avoids inserting stray spaces in case one of the names is nil, and also splits a fullname more effectively into first and last names; specifically, by splitting on the **last** space in the name, since "First Middle" "Last" is more of a human-compatible split than "First" "Middle Last". See examples:

```
# Before split
> puts p.name.inspect
"Prince"
"Test User"
"Jean Luc Picard"

# After split    
> puts p.first_name.inspect + " " + p.last_name.inspect
"" "Prince"
"Test" "User"
"Jean Luc" "Picard"
```

My main complaint is that "Prince" should probably be a first name not a last name, but then again depending on your database constraints it might need to go into the last_name field anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my rails 4 app with a User model I generated my migration file

```
rails g migration RemoveFirstLastNameColumnsFromUser
```

Then I put in

```
class RemoveFirstLastNameColumnsFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :name, :string

    User.all.each do |u|
      u.update! name: "#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}"
    end

    remove_column :users, :first_name
    remove_column :users, :last_name
  end

  def down
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string

    User.all.each do |u|
      n = u.name
      u.update! last_name: n.slice!(/\w+\z/)
      u.update! first_name: n.strip
    end

    remove_column :users, :name, :string
  end
end
```

This `#down` method will account for names with more than one space.